# using a timer as a highscore system

Tags: python, timer

i have a program where it asks the user a series of questions.
**im looking to start a timer when the user begins the program and want the timer to end and display the time used once the game is over when the questions are answered**. I have some code for a timer already but it brings a few problems. unless i execute this program using cmd, it prints a new line every second and also causes the cmd to keep flashing. it works as wanted when run from cmd though.
thanks for any help

```
import os
import time
s=0
m=0
h=0
while s<=60:
    os.system('cls')
    print (h, 'Hours', m, 'Minutes', s, 'Seconds')
    time.sleep(1)
    s+=1
    if s == 60:
        m+=1
        s=0
    elif m == 60:
        h+=1
        m=0
        s=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `time.time`:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()

# code for the game goes here

end_time = time.time()
difference = end_time - start_time      # in seconds

print("You took {} seconds".format(difference))
```

If you want to turn seconds into hours and minutes, you can use the modulo operator `%`, which finds a remainder, and the floor division operator `//` which ignores remainders:

```
time_in_seconds = 123456789
hours = time_in_seconds // (60*60)
minutes = (time_in_seconds % (60*60)) // 60
seconds = time in seconds % 60
```

Comment: @hennessyd No problem! If this answer helped you, it'd be great if you could accept it at some point.

Comment: is there a quick way to assign a time to a name in a scoring system?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - defining it as a function? The answer is yes, if the rest of your code is also a function.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of your code after the import write `startTime = time.time()`, then at the very end of your code write `totalTime = time.time() - startTime`. Then you can just print toalTime.